# Play Framework won't switch to port 80

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I've created a standalone java server using play dist.  It's using the following config file:

```
# This is the main configuration file for the application.
# ~~~~~

# Secret key
# ~~~~~
# The secret key is used to secure cryptographics functions.
# If you deploy your application to several instances be sure to use the same key!
application.secret="mysecretkey"
application.baseUrl="myurl"
application.mode=prod
# The application languages
# ~~~~~
application.langs="en"

# Global object class
# ~~~~~
# Define the Global object class for this application.
# Default to Global in the root package.
# application.global=Global

# Router 
# ~~~~~
# Define the Router object to use for this application.
# This router will be looked up first when the application is starting up,
# so make sure this is the entry point. 
# Furthermore, it's assumed your route file is named properly. 
# So for an application router like `conf/my.application.Router`,
# you may need to define a router file `my.application.routes`.
# Default to Routes in the root package (and `conf/routes`)
# application.router=my.application.Routes

# Database configuration
# ~~~~~ 
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
#
# db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
# db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
# db.default.user=sa
# db.default.password=""
#
# You can expose this datasource via JNDI if needed (Useful for JPA)
# db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS

# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# You can disable evolutions if needed
# evolutionplugin=disabled

# Ebean configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many Ebean servers as you want.
# By convention, the default server is named `default`
#
# ebean.default="models.*"

# Logger
# ~~~~~
# You can also configure logback (http://logback.qos.ch/), by providing a logger.xml file in the conf directory .

# Root logger:
logger.root=ERROR

# Logger used by the framework:
logger.play=INFO

# Logger provided to your application:
logger.application=DEBUG
http.port=80
```

For some reason, it's ignoring the entire config file.  It still thinks the baseUrl is the project name, and is binding to port 9000.  What am I doing wrong?  Below is the that's finally run on the server.

java -cp ./lib/org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.0.jar:./lib/play.play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:./lib/play.sbt-link-2.1.0.jar:./lib/org.javassist.javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar:./lib/play.play-exceptions-2.1.0.jar:./lib/play.templates_2.10-2.1.0.jar:./lib/com.github.scala-incubator.io.scala-io-file_2.10-0.4.2.jar:./lib/com.github.scala-incubator.io.scala-io-core_2.10-0.4.2.jar:./lib/com.jsuereth.scala-arm_2.10-1.3.jar:./lib/play.play-iteratees_2.10-2.1.0.jar:./lib/org.scala-stm.scala-stm_2.10.0-0.6.jar:./lib/com.typesafe.config-1.0.0.jar:./lib/io.netty.netty-3.5.9.Final.jar:./lib/org.slf4j.jul-to-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:./lib/org.slf4j.jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:./lib/ch.qos.logback.logback-core-1.0.7.jar:./lib/ch.qos.logback.logback-classic-1.0.7.jar:./lib/com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.1.0.jar:./lib/com.typesafe.akka.akka-slf4j_2.10-2.1.0.jar:./lib/org.slf4j.slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar:./lib/joda-time.joda-time-2.1.jar:./lib/org.joda.joda-convert-1.2.jar:./lib/org.apache.commons.commons-lang3-3.1.jar:./lib/com.ning.async-http-client-1.7.6.jar:./lib/oauth.signpost.signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar:./lib/commons-codec.commons-codec-1.3.jar:./lib/oauth.signpost.signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2.jar:./lib/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore-4.0.1.jar:./lib/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient-4.0.1.jar:./lib/commons-logging.commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:./lib/org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl-1.9.10.jar:./lib/org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.10.jar:./lib/net.sf.ehcache.ehcache-core-2.6.0.jar:./lib/javax.transaction.jta-1.1.jar:./lib/org.scala-lang.scala-reflect-2.10.0.jar:./lib/play.play-java_2.10-2.1.0.jar:./lib/org.yaml.snakeyaml-1.10.jar:./lib/org.hibernate.hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar:./lib/javax.validation.validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar:./lib/org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar:./lib/org.springframework.spring-context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:./lib/org.springframework.spring-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:./lib/org.springframework.spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:./lib/org.reflections.reflections-0.9.8.jar:./lib/com.google.guava.guava-13.0.1.jar:./lib/com.google.code.findbugs.jsr305-2.0.1.jar:./lib/javax.servlet.javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar:./lib/play.play-java-jdbc_2.10-2.1.0.jar:./lib/play.play-jdbc_2.10-2.1.0.jar:./lib/com.jolbox.bonecp-0.7.1.RELEASE.jar:./lib/com.h2database.h2-1.3.168.jar:./lib/tyrex.tyrex-1.0.1.jar:./lib/play.play-java-ebean_2.10-2.1.0.jar:./lib/org.avaje.ebeanorm.avaje-ebeanorm-3.1.2.jar:./lib/org.avaje.ebeanorm.avaje-ebeanorm-api-3.1.1.jar:./lib/org.avaje.ebeanorm.avaje-ebeanorm-agent-3.1.1.jar:./lib/org.avaje.ebeanorm.avaje-ebeanorm-server-3.1.2.jar:./lib/org.hibernate.javax.persistence.hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:./lib/huntress_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dconfig.file=./application.prod.conf play.core.server.NettyServer .

Edit: I know it's loading the file.  If there's an error in the file, such as a colon in a url not surrounded by quotes, it spits out an error and stops running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `http.port` thing is applicable to play framework 1.x only. To run your application on a port different than 9000 you should start the application like that:
`play "run 80"` (or `play "start 80"`)

Also consider that you must have sudo privileges to run the application on port <1024

***EDIT:*** as for the `start` script you should add the `http.port` parameter when running your script: `bash start -Dhttp.port=80`

Comment: play dist has given me a start script.  With the context of that, how do I set the port?  Is everything via the command line?  If so, what's the point of the application.conf file?

Comment: The `application.conf` is used to configure application-specific stuff and you may want to run multiple instances of one application on different ports

Comment: The whole difference between dev & ops. The application has configuration it needs to know in order to run (which database, where is the database, the main langage, etc). What it doesn't need to know (os, port, front load balancer, etc) is ops part of the deploy.

Comment: Ah, ok.  So what I am trying to do is bad practice.  However, I find it very odd and frustrating that it would just ignore what I have in my application.conf.  How about in development mode?  Will it still take these values from the Application.conf?  Or do I need to use command line arguments there too?  Is there a listing of what can be specified in application.conf?